# How to change permalinks for custom post types only

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I added a custom post type in functions.php.
And And I only changed the custom post type permalink in functions.php, but I get 404 Not Found page.
What should I do?

**functions.php**

```php
function add_custom_post_type(){
  register_post_type(
      'carrot',
      [
          'label' => 'Carrot',
          'public'        => true,
          'has_archive'   => true,
          'menu_position' => 5,
          'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-carrot',
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'supports' => [
              'title',
              'editor',
              'page-attributes'
          ]
      ]
  );
}
add_action('init', 'add_custom_post_type');

add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_post_type_link', 1, 2);
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules_array');

function my_post_type_link($link, $post){
  if($post->post_type === 'carrot'){
    return home_url('/carrot/'.$post->ID);
  } else {
    return $link;
  }
}
function my_rewrite_rules_array($rules){
  $new_rule = array(
    'carrot/([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=carrot&p=$matches[1]'
  );
  return $new_rule + $rules;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: select permalink settings as Post name

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Is it impossible to change the permalink only for the custom post type while keeping the Common Settings Plain?